# how do I delete everything below and to the right of a cell in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel

```
wOut.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D8", Range("D8").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents
```

this for example doesn't work (Application-defined or operation-defined error)

Answer (score 0):

```
With wOut.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Range(.Cells(8, 4), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @markrotteveel While I generally do so, in this forum which is for programmers, in my opinion the code itself is self-explanatory. Is there something specific that you do not understand?

Comment: You assume the code is self-explanatory, because you are probably knowledgeable in the ins and outs of this API. Such an assumption rarely holds for people new to an API, or with just a minimal understanding of the API. Your answer could be greatly improved by explaining why the code of the OP doesn't work, and how and why your code does work.

Comment: @markrotteveel Obviously, we have different approaches to encouraging learning, as well as what is simple and what is not for the average user of this particular forum.